# How to properly escape this regex patterns in java?

Tags: java, regex

This is the input I want to process. I want to extract the value of the `operation` attribute:

```
<h:outputLink value="#" id="temp_solution">
    <rich:componentContro
        for="panel"
        attachTo="temp_solution"
        operation="show"
        event="onclick"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

With the help of an [online regex tester](http://regex101.com/) I came up with the following regular expression

```
(?<=operation=")(\w+)(?=")
```

To be a bit more dynamic, I replaced `operation` with `%s` so I can use this template for different situations. But I encountered a problem, while trying to test my "creation" with the help of a small test program:

```
public class Main {
  private static final String INPUT = "<h:outputLink value=\"#\" id=\"temp_solution\">\n"
      + "    <rich:componentControl \n"
      + "        for=\"panel\" \n"
      + "        attachTo=\"temp_solution\" \n"
      + "        operation=\"show\""
      + "        event=\"onclick\"/>  \n"
      + "</h:outputLink>";

  private static final String REGEX_TEMPLATE = "(?<=%s=\")(\\w+)(?=\")";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String  actualRegex = String.format(REGEX_TEMPLATE, "operation");    
    final Pattern pattern     = Pattern.compile(actualRegex);
    final Matcher matcher     = pattern.matcher(INPUT);

    System.out.println("Regex: " + pattern);     
    System.out.println(matcher.matches() ? matcher.group(0) : "Nothing found");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Regex: (?<=operation=")(\w+)(?=")
Nothing found
```

Even double escaping the regex inside my code:

```
private static final String REGEX_TEMPLATE = "(?<=%s=\\\")(\\\\w+)(?=\\\")";
```

doesn't help:

```
Regex: (?<=operation=\")(\\w+)(?=\")
Nothing found
```

Please give me some advise on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your regex. However, it doesn't match the entire input, so you can't use [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()). Change it to [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), which only tries to find a matching subsequence:

```
System.out.println(matcher.find() ? matcher.group(0) : "Nothing found");
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I just became obsessed with the thought that something about the regex is incorrect. Didn't think to take a look on how it's being used. I'll accept your answer asap (there is a time limit).

Answer (score 1):

Try regex like this :

```
(?<=operation=\")(\w+)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/fL0jP1/2)

Comment: @Keppil answered, my regex is ok but the way I used it has been wrong. Thanks anyway for trying to help me!

Comment: @ifLoop - Always go with the *correct* answer.. :). I edited my regex and demo to select without quotes. :P

Comment: Yes it does what I want now and is a little bit shorter. I'll give you +1 for that neat addition :)